Show chatboxes in popup windows just like in facebook web as well as in fullscreen view mode
I have setup conversejs in fullscreen view mode. Like in Facebook when you click on a chat it opens the chat in a popup window, i want the same functionality in Conversejs as well. Chat boxes will be in fullscreen view mode always but I can open the chatbox in popup window also, any help would be really appreiciated
I tried the overlayed view mode but than the chat is only in popup window not in fullscreen, I want it in both places at once.
I also tried making plugins for that by copy pasting chatbox views etc but that's a very long way.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It's possible to change (some) settings at runtime. The view_mode setting is one of those.
You can try it for yourself in the browser's developer console.
First make sure the _converse object is globally available.
converse.plugins.add('converse-debug', {
    initialize () {
        const { _converse } = this;
        window._converse = _converse;
    }
});

converse.initialize({
    // Other settings not shown for conciseness
    view_mode: 'fullscreen',
    whitelisted_plugins: ['converse-debug'],
});

Then load Converse and open the browser's dev console (e.g. press F12) and in the console try the following:
_converse.api.settings.set('view_mode', 'overlayed');

Here's how you could do this via a plugin:
<button type="button" class="btn switch-view-mode">
    <converse-icon class="fas fa-refresh" size="1em"></converse-icon>
    Switch Mode
</button>

<script>
converse.plugins.add('switch-view-mode', {
    initialize () {
        const { _converse } = this;
        const button = document.querySelector('.switch-view-mode');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const { api } = _converse;
            const view_mode = api.settings.get('view_mode');

            if (view_mode == 'fullscreen') {
                api.settings.set('view_mode', 'overlayed');
            } else {
                api.settings.set('view_mode', 'fullscreen');
            }
        });
    }
});

converse.initialize({
    // Other settings not shown
    whitelisted_plugins: ['switch-view-mode'],
});
</script>


That's not possible currently.

Any suggestions on how i can achieve this functionality?
